# Use router on top of the old one

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router

After the router updated it's firmware, my WiFi turned into a mess. The speed dropped drastically and the signal got bad. The ISP denied to help me, so instead I decided to buy a new router.

I've connected the new router (Tenda AC6) to the old one (ZTEF680) via ethernet cable. (WAN port in new one -> LAN port in old one). The problem I am having is that the speed when connected to the new router is like 5x lower than it should be. (On cable connection).

When I connected the new router to the old one, I was expecting that it would share the same bandwidth over the cable, which is not the case.

What did I do wrong there? Should I first turn my old router in a bridge mode?

Comment: Is your old router slow via WiFi only, or via cable Ethernet connection as well?

Comment: My contracted speed is 600/600. Over the cable I get 650 stable, and over the WiFi I get like 200 unstable. Even if I place the device 1cm from the router, the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

I would hook it up differently:

1. Hook up a LAN port on the new router to a LAN port on your network (old router).
2. Give this new router a static IP address on the network so it can survive restarts and remain connected.
3. Turn DHCP OFF on the new router.

Now your new router is purely an extension and a wired connection on the new router should perform at the same speed as a wired connection on the old router.

Now set up wireless and test.

You should not need Bridged mode, but it will not harm anything to have Bridged mode

Comment: The problem I am having with connecting LAN -> LAN is that my connection doesn’t get recognized. Is a static IP a must? Could that be the issue?

Comment: Static IP is not a must but highly desirable. Log into the new router, select the LAN interface and give it an IP there that comes from your network in the non-DHCP range